# Multithreading printf() with semaphores in c

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, semaphore

What I want to achieve is for the three separate prints to be executed one after the other, printing the message “What a wonderful world!”. What I get instead is “what a what a what a wonderful wonderful wonderful world world world”. I think there is something wrong with the pthread_join(). The program will end when the user inputs ctrl+c.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t Asem;
sem_t Bsem;
sem_t Csem;

void *print_WhatA(){
    while(1){
        sem_wait(&Asem);
        printf("What A ");
        sem_post(&Bsem);
    }
} 

void *print_Wonderful(){
    while(1){
        sem_wait(&Bsem);
        printf("Wonderful ");
        sem_post(&Csem);
    }
}

void *print_World(){
    while(1){
        sem_wait(&Csem);
        printf("World!\n");
        sem_post(&Asem);
    }
}

void main(){
    sem_init(&Asem,0,0);    //initialization of the first semaphore
    sem_init(&Bsem,0,1);    //initialization of the second semaphore
    sem_init(&Csem,0,2);    //initialization of the third semaphore
    pthread_t A_thread;    
    pthread_t B_thread;
    pthread_t C_thread;
    pthread_create(&A_thread,NULL, print_WhatA,NULL);       //thread creation for print_WhatA function 
    pthread_create(&B_thread,NULL, print_Wonderfull,NULL);  //thread creation for print_Wonderful function
    pthread_create(&C_thread,NULL, print_World,NULL);       //thread creation for print_World function
    pthread_join(A_thread,NULL);
    pthread_join(B_thread,NULL);
    pthread_join(C_thread,NULL);
}
```

Comment: If you just want three things happen one after the other, don't create any threads. Threads are for things that happen one after, before, or simultaneously with the other. If you already have threads and want something in one thread to happen after something else in another thread, semaphores are the wrong tool for the job. You need condition variables.

Comment: @n.m. 'semaphores are the wrong tool for the job' - no, they are one right tool, as PSkocik demonstrates in the answer.

Comment: @MartinJames my bad, I read semaphore and think mutex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize semaphores B and C to 0 and semaphore A to 1.
This works:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t Asem;
sem_t Bsem;
sem_t Csem;

void *print_WhatA(){
    while(1){
        sem_wait(&Asem);
        printf("What A ");
        sem_post(&Bsem);
    }
} 

void *print_Wonderful(){
    while(1){
        sem_wait(&Bsem);
        printf("Wonderful ");
        sem_post(&Csem);
    }
}

void *print_World(){
    while(1){
        sem_wait(&Csem);
        printf("World!\n");
        sem_post(&Asem);
    }
}

void main(){
    sem_init(&Asem,0,1);    //initialization of the first semaphore
    sem_init(&Bsem,0,0);    //initialization of the second semaphore
    sem_init(&Csem,0,0);    //initialization of the third semaphore
    pthread_t A_thread;    
    pthread_t B_thread;
    pthread_t C_thread;
    pthread_create(&A_thread,NULL, print_WhatA,NULL);       //thread creation for print_WhatA function 
    pthread_create(&B_thread,NULL, print_Wonderful,NULL);  //thread creation for print_Wonderful function
    pthread_create(&C_thread,NULL, print_World,NULL);       //thread creation for print_World function
    pthread_join(A_thread,NULL);
    pthread_join(B_thread,NULL);
    pthread_join(C_thread,NULL);
}
```